# Validate the input text box?

Tags: jquery

```
<input id="edit-name" type="text" class="name"/>
```

The cursor focus in the text and did't enter a character then lose the focus, give a tip(please enter the name)

The cursor focus in the text box and then type a character in the text box, the error message removed.

my code:

```
    $('#edit-name').focus(function(){
        if($(this).val()!=''){
        $('.error-message').remove();
        }
    });
    $('#edit-name').blur(function(){
        if($(this).val()==''){
            $('.error-message').remove();
          $('#edit-name').after('<span style="color:red;" class="error-message" >please enter the name！</span>'); 
        }


});
```

there is something wrong with my code? although i enter a character in the text box, the error-message still there unless the cursor focus in the text again.

Answer (score 0):

You're using blur which means it will show the tooltip if you leave the input box having not entered anything. However, your question states you want to

> The cursor focus in the text and did't enter a character, give a tip(please enter the name)

which means that needs to be on focus as well, as the `else` condition. Something like this is what you're looking for:

```
     $('#edit-name').on('focus change', function(){
        if($(this).val()!=''){
        $('.error-message').remove();
        } else { 
          // what you're doing in the blur function
        }
    });
```

As soon as I focus on the input box I will see the tool-tip. `change` ensures that as soon as I type something, the tool-tip disappears.

*PS - Unless I got you wrong, and you really do want the tool-tip to appear on blur. In that case, ignore this answer.*

Comment: i am sorry, i forgot a condition. "then lose the focus"

Comment: i am sorry,i using your code, when the cursor  lose the focus. there is no  tooltip.